# Finding the rate constant of a first order reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> The reaction
>
> $\ce{A + B -> AB}$
>
> is 1st order with respect to **A** and zero order with respect to
>   **B**. The reaction is begun with the initial concentration of both reactants at $0.100 \,\text{M}$. After $1.5$ hours the concentration of
>   **B** has dropped to $0.060 \,\text{M}$. What is the approximate value of the specific rate (reaction rate) constant for this reaction?
>
> (A) $0.15$ **hr**$^{-1}$
>
> (B) $0.34$ **hr**$^{-1}$
>
> (C) $0.61$ **hr**$^{-1}$
>
> (D) the specific rate constant cannot be determined unless the
>   mechanism of the reaction known.

**My thoughts:** As the reaction is first order with respect to A and 0th order with respect to B, we can write the rate law as $\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -k[A]\to [A] =[A_0]e^{-kt} = 0.1e^{-kt}.$ Now, because A and B are in a 1:1 mole ratio, the concentration of A after 1.5 hours is also $0.06 \,\text{M},$ thus, we solve for $k$ as follows:
$$0.06=0.1e^{-k\cdot 1.5}$$
$$\to \ln(0.6)=-k\cdot 1.5$$
$$\to k = -\ln(0.6)/1.5\approx 0.34$$
Thus, the answer I obtained is B. However, the correct answer given is C. Is there any error in my work, or is the answer key wrong?

Comment: You're correct. There's a key mistake. Sounds like you could teach the author of the book you're referring :)